# How to do image reconstruction from array data?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, frequency-domain

i have 15 set of data which is the [s-parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_parameters), consist of 2 column (1001x2) each set. The first column is frequency and the second column is magnitude in dB. I have transform the magnitude from (dB) into value and frequency into time. But i have no idea how to transform these 15 sets of data into an image by using Matlab. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What do you mean? Make image from its FFT or simply plot graph?

Comment: Clarifications are needed on whether your s-parameter here refers to scattering parameters for a signal or not?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to reconstruct the image without the phase information.  The frequency magnitudes alone are not sufficient.

Comment: With some additional information it is possible to reconstruct from just magnitude information; it is known as 'solving the phase problem'.  But it is definitely an incomplete data problem.

Comment: Actually the data sets is obtained from a planar scanning of a phantom by using microwave. The output data that i get is only frequency and magnitude. Is that any other way to reconstruct a planar image from it?

Comment: @Ambbie, if you don't want to tell all needed information about your scanning method, you won't get any answer you want.

Comment: @Eddy_Em....The scanning mode is CST,i will obtain the frequency and magnitude in DB from the scanning method. I need to reconstruct the image using the information provided in scanning method which the data obtain is in frequency and magnitude. do you know anywhere can process this kind of data and make image reconstruction...Thanks